# Angular 4 component can be generated dynamically with index, but I cannot remove with the same index

Tags: angular

**I have followed this guidelnes: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent**

Component service class:

```
  @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) rootViewContainer: ViewContainerRef;
addComponent(component: ComponentModel) {
if(!component) {
    return;
}

let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.component);

let newComponent: ComponentModel = <ComponentModel>this.rootViewContainer.createComponent(factory, component.window.index, this.injector).instance;
newComponent.window = component.window;
console.log(newComponent);}

remove(index: number) {
console.log(this.rootViewContainer.remove(index));
console.log(this.rootViewContainer.detach(index));}
```

dynamicComponentContainer:

```
<div #dynamicComponentContainer></div>
```

What I am trying to achieve?
 - I want to add components with a button, that works. I want to delete a specific component, for example with a close button, it does not close the clicked component, button random one of the open components.

I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing (no hook, no constructor) but you have a component factory of type `ComponentFactoryResolver` so your constructor looks like this:

```
  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}
```

I'm assuming you're initializing that factory inside a `ngAfterContentInit` hook:

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const factory= this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AComponent);
    this.component = this.dynamicComponentContainer.createComponent(factory);
  }
```

Above, `this.component` is actually a `ComponentRef` and `AComponent` is the component you want to manipulate:

```
import { AComponent } from './a.component';

export class MainComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  component: ComponentRef<AComponent>;
```

You have your `ViewContainerRef` as well:

```
@ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;
```

Now since `this.component` is a `ComponentRef` you can destroy it:

```
  destroyComponent() {
    this.component.destroy();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for you aswer. What you are basically doing is destroying the current component  or the latest component in memory. This might work. I am willing to  remove/destory a specific conponent, in case you have more then one component. Have a look the link I have provided. That might be more clear.